# Can the standard HTML contextMenu attribute be used for CKEditor?

Tags: html, ckeditor

We use CKEditor 4.6.x for our site's content editing, but would like to use the standard HTML context menu instead of a custom menu as done by the CKEditor contextmenu addon. Is this something that's reasonably feasible?

For example, I want to have the table and link editing options in the context menu, but need to present the standard browser context menu, as well as the browser's built-in spell-check options. Currently as far as I can tell, the editor's context menu options can only be presented in the non-standard menu that is drawn by CKEditor itself.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create your own version of the contextmenu plugin, but that would work only for Firefox as no other browser supports this feature (http://caniuse.com/#search=contextmenu)

You best option is just to use the Ctrl key when you want to use the native context menu: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-browserContextMenuOnCtrl